# Cannot convert value of type [JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]

Tags: java, spring, jms, websphere, jndi

I have set up a JMSTemplate via JNDI like this:

```
<bean id="jmsTopicCancelacionTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="cancelacionTopic" />
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="oxmMessageConverter" />
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestResolver" />
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    </bean>

 <!-- look up the JMS ConnectionFactory in JNDI -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="requestQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jms/SchedulingRequestQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>JMS Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

However, when I try to bind the JNDI resource in my Websphere, I get the following error when starting up my application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate com.plexus.xesac_il.server.service.decide.DecideServiceImpl.jmsTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring/xesac-il-appcontext-jms.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring/xesac-il-appcontext-jms.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
    ... 133 more
```

It is my understanding that IBM's JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl should be implementing JmsTemplate or otherwise I wouldn't even have the chance to bind it through WebSphere, so what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JmsTemplate is a class from the Spring framework. So the class JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl has nothing to do with the JmsTemplate (the JmsTemplate uses the ConnectionFactory, but not the reversed way). However, i think your problem is, that you are packaging the JMS api classes in your application. When you deploy the application in WebSphere, WAS has also the API classes in the classpath, and you have a conflict, because there are two API jars in different classloaders. So just exclude the API jars from your deployment, and the error should be gone.

Comment: I know they're different; what I meant is that JmsTemplate is expecting a javax.jms.ConnectionFactory and that's what I am providing it with. When you talk about the api you mean I should exclude the jars containing javax.jms.ConnectionFactory to let WAS use his? Shouldn't that be avoided by configuring my project to PARENT_LAST class loading (which I already have)?

Comment: No, because then WebSphere uses his classes to initialize the JMS connection (because you configured it in WebSphere), and then Spring tries to use the connection object from WebSphere with the application specific class, which is the same code, but a different class object from a different classloader (you have just joined the classloader hell).

Comment: hi thanks for this thread it is very helpful. However I still have the issue after remove all ActiveMQ dependencies from WEB-INF/lib and also set WS class loader to parent-last and single class loader. Is there any other APIs I should exclude from deployment? Thank you.

Comment: Can you do a search in your IDE, if there's still a JAR left, which has the class ConnectionFactory in it? Eclipse and IntelliJ should show, which JAR hold a specific class, if you open it.